# osx ffmpeg avfoundation audio not in sync

Tags: ffmpeg, avfoundation, screen-recording

I'm trying to record my screen audio and video with ffmpeg. I have installed soundflower successfully and setup the correct audio devices. However, when using ffmpeg the audio is sped up and does not keep in sync with the video.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -y out.avi
```

I have also tried the following variations.

```
ffmpeg -vsync 2 -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -framerate 30 -y out.avi

ffmpeg -vsync 2 -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -frame_rate 30 -probesize 10M  -y out.avi

ffmpeg -async 1 -probesize 10M -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -r 15  -y out.avi

ffmpeg -async 15 -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -r 15  -y out.avi
```

I'm using ffmpeg version 2.6.2 installed via homebrew.

If someone has a free solution that isn't ffmpeg that works well from the command line then i will also accept that. Quicktime screen recording produces very large file sizes so it's not appropriate.

Comment: all of them are sped up?  What if you record just audio is it sped up? One option is to record with quicktime then convert with FFmpeg.

Comment: Just audio is sped up. Video plays back at normal speed. I'd love to use quicktime but the file sizes get really large really fast.

Comment: what if you record audio only, is it sped up?

Comment: I have the same problem under OSX (Yosemite and El Capitan). Anyone has a solution? (ffmpeg version git-2015-09-04-bd6610c)

Comment: @ rogerdpack - how do you record sound-only with ffmpeg? encoded with aac for instance.

Comment: @ChrisWhittington Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I get error when I run command via nstask in xcode for cocoa app: unknown input format : avfoundation. Tried ffmpeg 3.1.4, 3.3.1. Same error in  both. However the command works well in terminal.